What explains these surprising timings in numpy?
I recently timed several different array allocation and initialization procedures in numpy. I however fail to interpret these timings. Here is a plot of my measurements (size of array in number of elements "n" for a given data type vs time of execution).

If you want to reproduce the timings on your own machine, here is the code: https://gabrielfougeron.github.io/pyquickbench/_build/auto_examples/benchmarks/numpy_array_init.html#sphx-glr-build-auto-examples-benchmarks-numpy-array-init-py
In particular, here are my questions:

Why do the timings of np.ones and np.zeros differ so much?

Why is there a discontinuity around the few million elements mark?



Realted: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/18687

I'd say "full" and "ones" behave normally, and "zeros" and "empty" are covered here (look at the second picture).
